# What are the disadvantages to not using Unicode in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, unicode

What are the disadvantages to not using Unicode on Windows?

By Unicode, I mean `WCHAR` and the wide API functions. (CreateWindowW, MessageBoxW, and so on)

What problems could I run into by not using this?

Comment: What Windows calls "Unicode" is more accurately called "UTF-16", one of several *representations* of Unicode.

Comment: It is also little endian utf-16 to be precise

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/ provides in-depth discussion about what is right and what is wrong to do with Unicode on Windows for C++ programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code won't be able to deal correctly with characters outside the currently selected codepage when dealing with system APIs<sup>1</sup>.

Typical problems include unsupported characters being translated to question marks, inability to process text with special characters, in particular files with "strange characters" in their names/paths.

Also, several newer APIs are present only in the "wide" version.

Finally, each API call involving text will be marginally slower, since the "`A`" versions of APIs are normally just thin wrappers around the "`W`" APIs, that convert the parameters to UTF-16 on the fly - so, you have some overhead in respect to a "plain" `W` call.

---

1. Nothing stops you to work in a narrow-characters Unicode encoding (=>UTF-8) inside your application, but Windows "`A`" APIs [don't speak UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166503/utf-8-in-windows), so you'd have to convert to UTF-16 and call the `W` versions anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the gist of the original question was "should I compile all my Windows apps with "#define _UNICODE", and what's the down side if I don't?

My original reply was "Yeah, you should.  We've moved 8-bit ASCII, and '_UNICODE' is a reasonable default for any modern Windows code."

For Windows, I still believe that's reasonably good advice.  But I've deleted my original reply.  Because I didn't realize until I re-read my own links how much "UTF-16 is quite a sad state of affairs" (as Matteo Italia eloquently put it).

For example:

> http://utf8everywhere.org/
>
> Microsoft has ... mistakenly used ‘Unicode’ and ‘widechar’ as
>   synonyms for ‘UCS-2’ and ‘UTF-16’. Furthermore, since UTF-8 cannot be
>   set as the encoding for narrow string WinAPI, one must compile her
>   code with _UNICODE rather than _MBCS. Windows C++ programmers are
>   educated that Unicode must be done with ‘widechars’. As a result of
>   this mess, they are now among the most confused ones about what is the
>   right thing to do about text.

I heartily recommend these three links:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Should Know about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Should UTF-16 Be Considered Harmful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful)
- [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

IMHO...

Comment: Although the problems with their encoding are all true, I don't think it's fair to describe it as "mistakenly" as they adopted this at a time when unicode was effectively all 16 bit simple characters. The pain of trying to do the right thing, and being overtaken by changing standards...