# MinGW + GCC on Windows and UTF-8 characters

Tags: c, windows, gcc, utf-8, cmd

I'm having a trouble with GCC compiler and Windows CMD because I can't see the UTF-8 characters correctly. I've the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char caractere;
  int inteiro;
  float Float;
  double Double;

  printf("Tipo de Dados\tNúmero de Bytes\tEndereço\n");
  printf("Caractere\t%d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(caractere), &caractere);
  printf("Inteiro\t%d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(inteiro), &inteiro);
  printf("Float\t%d bytes \t\t em %d\n", sizeof(Float), &Float);
  printf("Double\t%d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(Double), &Double);

  printf("Caractere: %d bytes \t em %p\n", sizeof(caractere), &caractere);
  printf("Inteiro: %d bytes \t em %p\n", sizeof(inteiro), &inteiro);
  printf("Float: %d bytes \t\t em %p\n", sizeof(Float), &Float);
  printf("Double: %d bytes \t em %p\n", sizeof(Double), &Double);

  return 0;
}
```

And then I run the following command:

```
gcc pointers01.c -o pointers
```

I don't get any compiling errors. But when I execute the produced file (.exe) it doesn't show the UTF-8 characters:

```
Tipo de Dados   N├║mero de Bytes    Endere├ºo
Caractere   1 bytes      em 2686751
Inteiro 4 bytes      em 2686744
Float   4 bytes          em 2686740
Double  8 bytes      em 2686728
Caractere: 1 bytes   em 0028FF1F
Inteiro: 4 bytes     em 0028FF18
Float: 4 bytes       em 0028FF14
Double: 8 bytes      em 0028FF08
```

How do I do to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is a problem of the windows console. There are some workarounds, but none without "but"´s, ie. nothing works reliably in every situation.

Comment: Do you know some workaround? Even with "but"'s.

Comment: See the accepted answer and the first two comments (of the answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how (well, it isn´t really detailed either...maybe I get another link somewhere...)

Comment: Thank you. It works but it appears to have a lot of "buts"... I hope that with Windows 10 they improve this. =D

Comment: So... do you want to write the answer? Or should I give my own answer? O.o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166503/utf-8-in-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, the Windows console has very limited and buggy support for UTF-8.

What can be done: Set the codepage to `65001` and use one of the fonts which are supporting it, eg. "Lucida Console". The codepage can be set by the command `chcp` or, in C/C++, by the function `SetConsoleOutputCP`; the font is set with `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.

However, there are some major (and minor) problems. Minor first:

**a)** These functions are valid for one session, ie. if you run the program again later, you have to set it again. Making it default is possible in theory, but not recommendable, because it will affect all console programs and introduce the problems below to them, even if they don´t do anything with codepages and are not written to mitigate the problems.

**b)** If the console isn´t opened by the programn, but you´re starting it from an existing console, it will affect whatever runs after it, until this console is closed. So you have to change it back to the default value before your own program exits.

**c)** Some functions usable for console input/output won´t work properly with CP65001.
(that´s the most severe thing)

Unlike the whole UTF16 part of Windows, it partially treats UTF8 like any *1-byte* charset, and does some strange things which just happened to fulfill the standard with 1byte charsets, but are implemented differently.

As an example, fread should return the number of bytes read (if called with size 1), but in Microsofts implementation, it does return the number of characters (UTF16 is an exception, but not UTF8). With any normal codepage, it will work because 1char=1byte, but not with UTF8 ... wrong return value => wrong data processed

Another example, fflush can hang (at least is reported to, didn´t check). etc.etc.
And it doesn´t only affect standard C functions, but the direct Winapi calls too.

**d)** As a result of c), all batch files with UTF-8 characters (except the normal ASCII range) won´t work properly, at least in some Windows versions (didn´t check each one, but it´s very likely that Win10 still has this bug. MS shows no intention to fix it anytime soon.)

Some more reading for c and d: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4b91f49-6f60-4ffe-887a-e18e39250905/possible-bugs-in-writefile-and-crt-unicode-issues?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Just a thing, with Cygwin, when I compile a C program with accents on words, everything works perfectly. Now that I'm need of using TDM-GCC to create Go DLLs, errors appear on the words. This must have also be a problem with the compiler or something, or with Cygwin it wouldn't work, I suppose.

Comment: Why not just convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 before writing to the console?

Answer (score 0):

I usually save the source files as DOS( CP437 ) with Sublime Text and it works (at least for small programs).